# How to get 360 * 640 H264 encoded video on Android R

Tags: android, h.264, android-mediacodec

I am using NDKMediaCodec to encode video in H264 in below resolutions
240 * 426,
360 * 640,
480 * 854,
720 * 1280

Everything was working earlier to android R, But on android R there is an issue in encoding 360 * 640. I have tested on Pixel 3,Pixel 4 and Pixel 5.

I am creating encoder using

```
 encoder = AMediaCodec_createCodecByName("OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc"); //i have also tried AMediaCodec_createEncoderByType("video/avc");
```

And configuring it as

```
    AMediaFormat *format = createMediaFormat(width, height);
    AMediaFormat_setString(format, "mime", "video/avc");
    AMediaFormat_setInt32(format, "i-frame-interval", IFrameDuration);
    AMediaFormat_setInt32(format, "bitrate", bps);
    AMediaFormat_setInt32(format, "frame-rate", fps);
    AMediaFormat_setInt32(format, "bitrate-mode", 1);
    AMediaFormat_setInt32(format, "profile", 1); // AVCProfileBaseline
    AMediaFormat_setInt32(format, "level", 512); // AVCLevel31
    
    if (FORMAT_21_REQUIRED) {
        AMediaFormat_setInt32(format, "color-format", 21);
    }
    else {
        AMediaFormat_setInt32(format, "color-format", 19);
    }
    if ((status = AMediaCodec_configure(encoder, format, NULL, NULL, AMEDIACODEC_CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE)) == AMEDIA_OK) {
        if ((status = AMediaCodec_start(nativeCodec_data->enc_Amedia)) != AMEDIA_OK) {
            //error handle
        }
    }
    else {
        //error handle
    }
    AMediaFormat_delete(format);
```

If i create encoder like this on earlier versions of android R, it chooses OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc. But in android R it chooses c2.qti.avc.encoder, even if i specify qcom video encoder.

For 360 * 640 configuration, encoder is producing corrupted image. From SPS and PPS, i can see encoder is generating 368 * 640 resolution with no cropping. If i create encoder with 368 * 640, then there is no issue observed.

If i use OMX.google.h264.encoder, then everything works fine even for 360 * 640. Only problem is with using OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc and 360 * 640 as resolution.

I am not using any surface, and encoding by passing YUV buffers directly, I have dumped the YUV to file and checked, there is no issue with YUV

```
    ibufidx = AMediaCodec_dequeueInputBuffer(encoder, 0);
    AMediaCodec_queueInputBuffer(encoder, ibufidx, 0, bufsize,timeStamp,flags);
```

I want to achieve 360 * 640 encoding with OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc on android R. Anyone faced this issue or any suggestions?

I am observing issue on pixel 3, pixel 4 and pixel 5 with android R. I have tested on wide range of devices from embedded devices to samsung latest flagship devices upto android Q. So far tested only pixel devices with android R and observing the issue.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64492872/edit) your post to include which devices your code was tested on.

Comment: Updated my post, android R is tested only on pixel 3,4 and 5 devices, and observed issue on all the devices. The code was implemented 2 years ago and was working fine on all the devices (from embedded devices to latest flagship devices) untill Android Q.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for why `OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc` is required? You may wish to file a [bug report](https://source.android.com/setup/contribute/report-bugs) as it appears to a regression.

Comment: Hi, From what we believe OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc uses the codec on qualcomm chips, which are hardware accelerated. There is no document specifying so. Any idea if OMX.google.h264.encoder uses hardware or software codec. We want to use only hardware accelerated video codecs. I will open bug report, thanks.

Comment: FYI: Exoplayer commit for Exoplayer function  `isSoftwareOnly(android.media.MediaCodecInfo codecInfo) `: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/commit/48555550d7fcf6953f2382466818c74092b26355

Comment: Thanks, I will add the code to dynamically fetch the codecs and choose hardware codec.